# GitLab CI review enviroment with docker

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

So environment deploy on feature branch for review before merge is great option. I have 10+ projects with similar structure and same docker image. There is gulp for front-end and php framework for backend. 
I made a little changes in .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
deploy:review:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - rsync -av --delete httpdocs/ /home/gitlab-runner/dev_env/$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME.$CI_PROJECT_NAME.$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME
    url: http://$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME.$CI_PROJECT_NAME.$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE.env.mydomain.com
  only:
    - branches
  except:
    - master
```

And i configured nginx for loading folder for every subdomain. Thats work great for reviewing fronted part. 
But i want to use docker for backend part. So i need somehow to start docker on same server where gitlab is. Then i need to hold all port generation and maybe nginx redirect routine. And last part, after merge or after few days i need to romove review docker.

I believe this https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy can help me control ports, but i need to generate them (using CI build id as port seems to be buggy, one day i'll have build #65536) and still question about auto start/stop/destroy containers.

May be there is some opensource docker cloudsolution for standalone server?

Comment: So i guess kubernetes might be a solution. But still question about port reuse after review ended and auto remove review enviroment.

Comment: jwilder/nginx-proxy - totally get ports routine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First part solved.

**jwilder/nginx-proxy** - totally get ports routine.

I run proxy on startap:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 443:443 --name "dnginx" -v /root/certs:/etc/nginx/certs -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro -v /var/log/nginx-proxy/:/var/log/nginx/ jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

then run each container like this:

```
sudo docker run -d --name "nginx-test" --expose 80 --env VIRTUAL_HOST=test.domain.com kitematic/hello-world-nginx
```

note VIRTUAL_HOST=test.domain.com and --expose 80

**--env VIRTUAL_HOST=test.domain.com**
will say nginx-proxy wich subdomain to link with container

**--expose 80**
if your container doesn't exposes port itself. This will open 80 port inside docker network. And nginx-proxy will autogenerate new config, adding part for your subdomain.

Second part solved:

I made my docker runner privileged in gitlab runner config.toml. Then my runner job works like this:

```
deploy to review:
  image: docker:latest
  tags:
    - privileged
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - mkdir -p /home/devenv/$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE-$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME/project
    - cp -r ./* /home/devenv/$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE-$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME/project
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - ( docker stop $CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE-$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME && docker rm $CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE-$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME ) || echo "nothing to stop, starting new container"
    - docker run -d --env VIRTUAL_HOST="$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME.$CI_PROJECT_NAME.$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE.mydomain.com" --name "$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE-$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME" -v /home/devenv/$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE-$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME/project:/home/project -v /home/devenv/$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE-$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME/logs:/var/logs myrepo.com:4567/group/projectimage
    - docker exec $CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE-$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME /bin/sh /home/project/build.sh
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME
    url: http://$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME.$CI_PROJECT_NAME.$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE.mydomain.com
  only:
    - branches
  except:
    - master
```

Where build.sh is npm+bower install command and gulp tasks.